# Why am i not able to get as accurate result as Google latitude on same device at the same time

Tags: android, gps, criteria, locationmanager

**Prologue:**
I have seen many posts regarding improving the GPS performance and accuracy in android devices.
But i am just curios and a little embarrassed at the result that my GPS tracking app gives. Especially when i compare it with the result i get from Google latitude.

**Here is MY problem:**

> Why am i not able to get as accurate result as Google latitude on same device at the same time.

I used the 'Criteria' facility to customize my result and provider as follows

```
Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_HIGH); 
provider = locmgr.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
```

I am able to GPS location results with an accuracy of 800-900 meters in a testing Device : LG Optimus pro . 
The Google latitude app shows a much finer result as the location of the device.
Is there any sort of caching being done by the app.. or any more finer criteria tweaks.

I really love to see my app giving an accuracy of 20 to 30 meters or more ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Use Android's native location framework, it all depends on your GPS chipset and weather conditions at the time, but through [LocationManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html) I'm usually able to get at least a 20m accuracy. Check [this tutorial](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html) out.

You can specify whether or not to work with network provided location for example, which when provided by Cell-ID might be highly inaccurate but by WiFi highly misleading, both of them can help you get approximate locations when GPS satellites are not an option.